# How to choose the right MOSFET?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches, actuator

I am looking to use a MOSFET to switch  a linear actuator on and off. There's nothing else on the circuit, just the switch and the actuator (and a Raspberry Pi to control the switch.)

The actuator takes 7.8V to engage and draws 1.26A of current. There's no datasheet for the actuator so those are all of the numbers I have.

- How do I pick the right MOSFET?
- What are important variables to consider?
- Is there some sort of website that I can use to filter through all of the options based on those variables?

Comment: A bit of advice: for mosfets as switches, the drive voltage should be taken from the rds,on  spec, where it says what the Vgs used was. That will give you a safe drive to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Picking the right Mosfet**

Theare are several basic tutorial with the topic "Using MOSFET as a Switch", for example [this one](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html) or [this](https://www.digikey.in/en/blog/how-to-select-a-mosfet-for-logic-circuits-or-gate-design).

**The minimum parameters you should consider are:**

- V<sub>DS</sub>MAX: Choose it higher than the supply voltage. 60 V mosfets are commonly available.
- V<sub>gs th</sub>: Control voltage. If you are using a RPI, the outputs are 3,3 V so pick something that can turn ON the mosfet. Check charts V<sub>DS</sub> Vs I<sub>D</sub> parametric depending on V<sub>gs</sub>
- R<sub>DS on</sub>: The smaller, the lower the conduction loses.
- Add a freewheeling diode to the actuator in order to protect the mosfet.

**Websites to filter**

You can perform a parametric search on any electronics component dealer:
[Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors/Transistors/MOSFET/_/N-ax1sf),  [newark](https://www.newark.com/c/semiconductors-discretes/fets/single-mosfets), [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?s=N4IgTCBcDaILYHsDOAzApgFxAXQL5A)...

**Example**
With that in mind, a couple of examples: Mosfets: PMV37ENEAR (SMD) or IRFZ24NPBF (Through hole) and for diode 1N4001 will be enough. Asuming you are not doing PWM.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEffud.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: *Asuming you are not doing PWM.* You **can** do PWM even with "slow" components, just keep the PWM frequency low, like lower than a few kHz. Realize that if you do that, you might hear (as a sound) that PWM frequency.